# Breeze.js: missing property in returned server metadata

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

It looks like breeze is failing to include some properties in the returned metadata from the server. I am using breeze.js on the client and breeze-EF on the server without further configuration. This is my object

```
[Table("COEP")]
public class COEP : DataObject
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string COEMID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string COJPID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CORGID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CODPID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short? COEPISMAIN { get; set; }

    DateTime? STARTDATE { get; set; }

    DateTime? ENDDATE { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual COEM COEM { get; set; }
}
```

And here is **part** of the metadata returned from the server with the call: xxxController.GetMetadata() ( I just took the part concerning the object **COEP**)

> {"name":"**COEP**","customannotation:ClrType":"StampDev.Pro.v3.server.EndPoints.Comp.Data.COEP, StampDev.Pro.v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
>   "key":{"propertyRef":{"name":"ID"}},
>   "property":[
>       {"name":"**ID**","type":"Edm.String","maxLength":"128","fixedLength":"false","unicode":"true","nullable":"false"},
>       {"name":"**COEMID**","type":"Edm.String","maxLength":"128","fixedLength":"false","unicode":"true","nullable":"false"},
>       {"name":"**COJPID**","type":"Edm.String","maxLength":"Max","fixedLength":"false","unicode":"true","nullable":"false"},
>       {"name":"**CORGID**","type":"Edm.String","maxLength":"Max","fixedLength":"false","unicode":"true","nullable":"false"},
>       {"name":"**CODPID**","type":"Edm.String","maxLength":"Max","fixedLength":"false","unicode":"true","nullable":"false"},
>       {"name":"**COEPISMAIN**","type":"Edm.Int16","nullable":"false"}]
>       "navigationProperty":{"name":"COEM","relationship":"Self.COEM_COEP","fromRole":"COEM_COEP_Target","toRole":"COEM_COEP_Source"}}

You can clearly see that the properties "STARTDATE" and "ENDDATE" (nullable datetime) have not been included.

These properties are not marked with the [NotMapped] attribute. They should be included in the metadata. I cannot thing of what could go wrong here. These properties are fields present in the table in my MS SQL database.

The weird thing is that I have other objects with STARTDATE Datetime properties and they are properly returned in metadata. On more thing: the object "**COEP**" is the second level child in the 
master-child-child relationship, where **COEP** is a second level child. Any help, any hint to what could go wrong will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You omitted the `public` access modifiers for `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE`. Therefore, these properties are **private** by default, **not mapped to the table, and not exposed in metadata**.  Easy thing to miss (as I discovered scratching my head for the last half hour).

Why is `COEPISMAIN` both `[Required]` and optional (`short?`)?

Comment: Thank you very much @ward. I was in a hurry, behind deadlines, I did not see it. Also required and short? was a mistake (copy paste...)